# How to truncate the table value parameters (TVP) in TSQL?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, t-sql

I want to truncate the TVP instead of DROPPING.

When I am writing TRUNCATE TYPE  it is giving error.

DROP TYPE  is working but iI want TRUNCATE

Can any one help me with the syntax?

thank you

Comment: You should try to accept answers that seem correct, or that help you solve your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008, a Table Valued Parameter is ReadOnly in the TSQL code.

> To modify the data that is passed to a
>   stored procedure or parameterized
>   statement in table-valued parameter,
>   you must insert the data into a
>   temporary table or into a table
>   variable.

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The TVP is a *table variable* of a certain user-defined *table type*. The type is like a class and the variable like an instance. You can `drop` the user-defined table type, but then you couldn't use it as a TVP.

As the TVP, the table variable is read-only. In other contexts, you could `delete` all rows from the table variable, but you can never `truncate` it. Only user tables and temporary tables can be truncated.

You could copy the TVP into a temporary table and then truncate that, but I'm not sure what use that would be!